# ¿Cómo hacer un ".change" con 2 id en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Es que quiero que un `.change` en javascript haga efecto con 2 `id` o incluso más no sé si sea posible. ya intenté varias formas y esta fue la que me pareció más lógica, pero evidentemente no funciona.

```
 $("#tamano", "#materiales").change(function() {
            var tamano = $(this).val()
            var data = tamano.split("/")
            var cant1 = document.getElementById("CANT1").value
            var material = document.getElementById("material").value
            var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value
            $("#PAP").val(data[0])
            $("#EXV").val(data[1])
            $("#AV").val(data[2])
            var q1 = (cant1/data[1]*data[2]/12*0.3048)
            $("#mat1").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
            $("#mat2").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
            $("#mat3").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
            $("#mat4").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
            var core = document.getElementById("core").value
            var rollo = document.getElementById("rollo").value
            $("#core1").val(core/rollo);
        });
```

Es aquí justamente donde no sé si sea así `$("#tamano", "#materiales").change(function()`

Comment: puedes ponerle un attributo en comun ejemplo `data-change="comun"` o agregar el cuerpo de change a un funcion y llamarla luego...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
$("#tamano,#materiales")
```

Answer (score 1):

La razón de lo que te pasa es que el selector de la función de **JQuery** que usas está mal construido. Le estás pasando dos argumentos cuando lo que espera es recibir solamente uno (un **string** con el selector **CSS** a utilizar).

Lo mejor es no abusar de las funciones anónimas. Metiendo el contenido de tu función en una con nombre podrías llamarla desde donde quieras, incluso desde el `onchange` de dos elementos.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#input1').change(mi_funcion);
  $('#input2').change(mi_funcion);
});

function mi_funcion () {
  console.log('¡Me cambio!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
```

Otra manera de hacerlo poniéndole una misma clase a tus dos elementos y en el selector de tu función usar la clase en vez del ID.

```
$(".miclase").change(function() {
  var tamano = $(this).val()
  var data = tamano.split("/")
  var cant1 = document.getElementById("CANT1").value
  var material = document.getElementById("material").value
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value
  $("#PAP").val(data[0])
  $("#EXV").val(data[1])
  $("#AV").val(data[2])
  var q1 = (cant1/data[1]*data[2]/12*0.3048)
  $("#mat1").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
  $("#mat2").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
  $("#mat3").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
  $("#mat4").val(q1*data[0]*material/cant1*cantidad)
  var core = document.getElementById("core").value
  var rollo = document.getElementById("rollo").value
  $("#core1").val(core/rollo);
});
```

Aunque siempre recomendaré usar la función con nombre, de esa manera si deseas que la función se lance en otro tipo de evento, como un `onclick` podrías hacerlo sin mayor problema.